# HIbernate mapping on the wrong froreign key

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, mapping

I have 2 classes Device and Position that have a relation one-to-many/many-to-one (One device has several positions, a position is associated to one and only one device).

I have clearly specified in the hibernate mapping file that I want my table to join on device.DeviceID = position.FK_DeviceID, yet when i execute the following HQL query:

```
String queryString =  "select position" 
                        + " from Position position join position.device device"
                        + " where device.MACAddress = '" + macAddress + "'";
```

I keep getting the error : `" ERROR: Unknown column 'position0_.deviceID' in 'field list' "`, indicating me that he tries to join  on "deviceID" and not "FK_deviceID".

Here are the classes and the mapping files:

Position:

```
private Integer positionID;
private Coordinate coordinate;
private Date timestamp;
private Device device;
```

Device:

```
private Integer deviceID;
private String MACAddress;
private String name;
private Set<Position> positions;
```

Device mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="fr.utbm.LO53_IPS.models.Device" table="device" catalog="bdd_LO53">
    <id name="deviceID" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="deviceID" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="MACAddress" type="string">
        <column name="MACAddress" length="45" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="Name" type="string">
        <column name="Name" length="45" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <set name="positions" cascade="all">
        <key column="FK_DeviceID"/>
        <one-to-many class="fr.utbm.LO53_IPS.models.Position" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Position mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="fr.utbm.LO53_IPS.models.Position" table="position" catalog="bdd_LO53">
    <id name="PositionID" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="deviceID" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Timestamp" type="java.sql.Date">
        <column name="Timestamp" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="device" column="FK_DeviceID" 
        class="fr.utbm.LO53_IPS.models.Device" not-null="true"/>
    <component name="Coordinate" class="fr.utbm.LO53_IPS.models.Coordinate">
        <property name="x" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="x" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="y" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="y" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </component>
</class>
```

Sorry for the long post, I really can't figure out what part is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mapping for class Position, when you declare the id you are specifying a column called deviceID, which is a bit strange, because you should have a column PositionID, since you are in the table Position.

On the other hand, you can easily join like this: from Position p where p.device.MACAddres='....' without using join explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed this "deviceID" field, which was really stupid. And thanks for the simplification of the request